# Upgrading from Visual Studio 2013 Professional to Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

From the feature comparison between Visual Studio 2015 Professional and Community, I understand that the Community is missing some functionality:

- CodeLens
- many TFS features
- MSDN

Since I use it for private development only, I have not set up TFS and I don't need MSDN. CodeLens was not available in VS2013 Professional, so I don't miss it.

I'm using several VS plugins, but the new Community Edition even supports plugin. Maybe I have to buy updates for some of my plugins.

Thus it seems, I could simply "upgrade" from VS2013 Professional to VS2015 Community, if ...

Are there any other known differences between these two versions, which are not listed on Microsoft websites?

Comment: you might get answers here but I  guess this is more of a stackoverflow question 'cos they deal a lot with development environments too, even text editor development environments like sublime, so very much with something like visual studio , and they have a larger community there. Eithere way, hopefully neither will consider it too subjective, and you'll get answers at least.

Comment: The realtime diagnostic tools are pretty cool in 2015. The only thing I missed was the reference count / links that I got with 2013 Pro. The CodeLens reference count is the only downgrade, everything else is the same or better IMO. Get the new syntax options with C#6 too.

Comment: Just saw you mentioned CodeLense wasn't in 2013 Pro, you are right. I guess I had Ultimate.

Comment: Also it didn't replace 2013 at all, they are both installed for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, things work quite well and I didn't miss a feature of Visual Studio 2013 yet.

Luckily I was able to upgrade most plugins to their latest version for free so that Visual Studio 2015 support is provided. Plugins I use:

- NCrunch 2.15.0.9
- DevExpress 15.1.6
- ReSharper 2015.2
- OzCode 2.0.0.992
- PostSharp 4.1.23
- Visual Assist 2.0.74
- VisualSVN 5.1.0

ReSharper still shows errors in my Unit Tests although the solution compiles fine and I cleared the caches. I did not yet figure out what's wrong. It's a bit annoying to see so much code in red.

*Update:* these went away after upgrading the DevExpress controls to the latest version.

Visual Assist and Resharper sometimes get in conflict regarding syntax highlighting. But since ReSharper supports C++ now, the question is whether I need Visual Assist at all. At the moment I turn off Visual Assist.

All in all, I'll stay with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.